# Redirect strange url to 404

Tags: apache, rule

I dunno why, but my apache server accepts url like this

`//site.com/page.php/images/someimage.jpg` 
`//site.com/page2.php/icons/someimage.png` 
As a result i see page.php without images and with disabled javascript.
What i need to write in htaccess to redirect all that urls to 404?

Answer (score 0):

ErrorDocument 404 /your404errorPage.php?

Just remember to have RewriteEngine On